# Copying filtered table doesn't work as it is expected in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a small table and want to copy it after filtering. The image is in below,

[image]

and I have filtered it to shows only the red font color of the column "Days" as follows:

[image]

Now everything is ready to start the copying!
So I select all the table (Double CTRL+A inside the table) then go into the "Go to special" dialog box and choose the "Visible cells only". Then I simply copy that selected filtered range of that table and paste it as follows:

As it's clear, the right-side of the image shows the result of the copy-paste which of course is very odd! 
Why not all of the visible rows are pasted please?

[image]

Comment: I think you are referring to the last screen shot by saying "isn't clear". OK I can update it but I showed that because I wanted to show the animated area of the table when it is selected as copied area. And in the right-hand the result! You can just look at the second image and the look at the last one (right-hand) as the result.

Comment: Wait, did you paste directly to the right of the source table like it appears in the screen shot?  If so, your paste was complete, but pasted into rows that are hidden...  Fri is in hidden row 6, Sat-$3M is in hidden row 9, etc.

Comment: WOW. I think you solved the problem. I'm going to test it as fast as possible.!!

Comment: Yes. That's right. Write an answer to get +1 vote :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you've pasted the selection directly to the right of the source table which is filtered.  As filtering hides the entire row, your paste data is complete, but some rows of it reside in hidden rows.  So, paste into a new sheet, or below the source table.

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION:
Filter is applied, so row 6, 9, 13 and 14 are hidden.. so when you paste in the same lines of rows, so the second row of your filtered table mon $3,300.00 is pasted in 6th row, which is hidden... so paste it in new work sheet or work book.. or scroll down to somewhere and paste it.

Comment: I did that. But just like other ways of selecting and copying-pasting, the result was incomplete!